# How to assign value to input field?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

Im working on html content to disply data in mvc view binding data from model class, my requirement is to set values to input fields to html content from c#.
i want final content should come up with html content and values from model.
EXAMPLE:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my html content which is coming from text file. i've data in my model, i.e,

```cs
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string fname { get; set; } = "Stack"; 
    public string lname { get; set; } = "OverFlow";
}
```

In View :

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the HtmlHelper class is for.

Set the view model in your view file and create a form around it.

```
@model Models.EmployeeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employees", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.fname)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fname)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Invoke the view from your controller with an instance of the model to edit.

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ...
    employee = service.GetEmployeeById(id);

    return View(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one thig you could try would be to set values in Razor:

```cs
// your controller
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new EmployeeModel());// pass the actual viewmodel instance to the view here
        }
    }
```

```cs
@model EmployeeModel
.......
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="@Model.fname"><br><br> <!-- reference @Model fields as usual -->
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="@Model.lname"><br><br><!-- reference @Model fields as usual -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and a fiddle for you to play with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/37asAw